# Magnetic Dipole Radiation of a Small Center-fed Antenna

Tags: electromagnetism, dipole

I have a small center-fed antenna at z axis with a length of d, I have calculated the radiation fields and power, but I want to understand if there is magnetic dipole radiation. I assume there is none, the electric dipole dominates, how can I justify it?

Thanks!

Comment: In any realistic situation there will be all kinds of stuff there. Perhaps it would be better to draw a diagram and define precisely what your currents are. Why not simply integrate the currents and find the corresponding multipole moments?

Comment: Having said that, I would also assume that electric dipole will dominate. The power radiated by a source scales as a square of the dipole moment. Electric dipole moment scales proportionately to the size of the current distribution, magnetic dipole, as a square of the size. Hence as the size decreases electric dipole tends to win, but this is hand-waving

Comment: You are correct, that is how it works. What I think is to calculate magnetic dipole moment integral to see that if it goes to zero because of the vector multiplication.